# Gitlab trig a job manullay on merge request and trig it automatically in deployment pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to have the possibility to trig a job manullay on the Merge requests and also that this same job trig automatically in the pipelines deployment.

I check the gitlab documentation and I conclude to this :

```
  rules:
    - if: '...'
      when: manual
```

The problem here is that I don't know what to put in the `if` to indicate that We are in a Merge Requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` env var

```
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "master"'
      when: manual
```

In this case the rule it will apply if you are not on master branch (after merge your MR)